# Undefined variable in wp_add_inline_style()

Tags: wordpress, customization, php-8, inline-styles, undefined-variable

I updated the website to PHP8 and getting the Warning "Undefined variable $customVariables" on the last line with wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-style', $customVariables );
The code is below:

```
function spectra_custom_styles($custom) {
    //Fonts
    $headings_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_headings_fonts'));
    $body_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_body_fonts'));
    if ( $headings_font or $body_font) {
        $customVariables = ":root{"."\n";
        if ( $headings_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $headings_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-heading-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        if ( $body_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $body_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        
        $customVariables .= "}";
        
    }

    //Output all the styles
        wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-style', $customVariables );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you only define `$customVariables` inside your `if` block.  In the case `$headings_font or $body_font` evaluates to `false` the variable will be `Undefined`.

You can update to this:

```
function spectra_custom_styles($custom) {
    //Fonts
    $headings_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_headings_fonts'));
    $body_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_body_fonts'));
    $customVariables = "";

    if ( $headings_font or $body_font) {
        $customVariables .= ":root{"."\n";
        if ( $headings_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $headings_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-heading-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        if ( $body_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $body_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        
        $customVariables .= "}";
        
    }

    //Output all the styles
        wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-style', $customVariables );
}
```

or you can move `wp_add_inline_style` to inside the if block:

```
function spectra_custom_styles($custom) {
    //Fonts
    $headings_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_headings_fonts'));
    $body_font = esc_html(get_theme_mod('spectra_body_fonts'));


    if ( $headings_font or $body_font) {
        $customVariables = ":root{"."\n";
        if ( $headings_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $headings_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-heading-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        if ( $body_font ) {
            $font_pieces = explode(":", $body_font);
            $customVariables .= "--c7-font-family: {$font_pieces[0]};"."\n";
        }
        
        $customVariables .= "}";


    //Output all the styles
        wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-style', $customVariables );
        
    }

}
```